# How can I change the amount of memory dedicated to pycharm?

Tags: pycharm, out-of-memory

I am coding a chess program using a monte carlo tree search, simulating 800 games per move, which will later be guided by a neural network. The code works on my school's PCs but not on my new laptop, which has more memory than the school's (it has 16GB of RAM I believe), but gives me a MemoryError none the less.

I've tried changing the max memory limit in the "Edit Custom VM Options" section of Pycharm, from 2040mb to 4000mb, but it didn't change anything and I later found out that the school computer's limit was 750mb in the first place. I have had a look at TaskManager and it seems that my laptop crashes once the program hits about 1.6gb of memory used. the school's continues on up until it hits 2.6gb or so, and I haven't seen it crash.

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hughs\PycharmProjects\Chess\Monte_Carlo_Tree_Search.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.visit_count = 0
MemoryError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hughs/PycharmProjects/Chess/Chess.py", line 781, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/hughs/PycharmProjects/Chess/Chess.py", line 774, in main
    moves, wins = play_game("computer", wins)
  File "C:/Users/hughs/PycharmProjects/Chess/Chess.py", line 355, in play_game
    castle_queenside, move_counter, moves, king_loc)
  File "C:\Users\hughs\PycharmProjects\Chess\AI.py", line 11, in get_ai_move
    move = mcts.run_mcts(config, game)
MemoryError


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Before giving this error, it slows down its search from taking about 0.2 - 0.3 seconds per game simulation to 30 seconds - 1 minute per game simulation. (Yes, I know that is hideously slow in the first place and I will need to improve my efficiency).

I would appreciate anything pointing me towards what I should be looking into to fix this.

Comment: The problem is not with memory used by PyCharm but with your Python process consuming too much.

Comment: @PavelKarateev, I know that my python process uses loads of memory, but it's a sad necessity when using a monte carlo tree search as the information about a lot of nodes has to be held. My laptop should definitely be able to handle this, but the amount of memory given to the process is insufficient, and my question was about how to change this.

Comment: Actually, appologies @PavelKarateev as it turns out that I was saving all of the past boards for a draw by repetition, which significantly increased the memory consumption.